# How to show timer using php?

Tags: php, jquery

code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Timer</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <?php
        $dbSessionDuration = "1:30:00";
        list($hour,$min,$sec) = explode(':', $dbSessionDuration);
        $dbSessionDurationTime = mktime(0,0,0,$hour,$min,$sec);
    ?>
    <div class="count"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var millis = <?php echo $dbSessionDurationTime; ?>
        function displaytimer(){
            var hours = Math.floor(millis / 36e5),
                mins = Math.floor((millis % 36e5) / 6e4),
                secs = Math.floor((millis % 6e4) / 1000);
                $('.count').html(hours+':'+mins+':'+secs);  
        }
        setInterval(function(){
            millis -= 1000;
            displaytimer();
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code I want to create a timer and the time will start after `1:30:00` and then it decrease by second like `1:29:59` then `1:29:58` like this but now when I  use to get time inside the `class="count"` not happen. I don't know why? So, How can I fix this issue? please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Look at your browser debugger (F12) for the js error

Comment: I run your code there is no problem. Check if `mktime(0,0,0,$hour,$min,$sec);` gives correct millisecond. Otherwise your js code is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two notes on your code :-

-If you want to convert a variable from php to javascript you should echo it inside double/single quote.

-you need to get the total time in `millis` since you are using this `millis` to regenerate your time again so this is the equation to convert your time to millis `( ( intval($hour) * 60 * 60 ) + ( intval($min) * 60 ) + ( intval($sec) ) ) * 1000`.

**Code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $dbSessionDuration = "1:30:00";
        list($hour,$min,$sec) = explode(':', $dbSessionDuration);
        $dbSessionDurationTime =  ( ( intval($hour) * 60 * 60 ) + ( intval($min) * 60 ) + ( intval($sec) ) ) * 1000;
    ?>
    <div class="count"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var millis = '<?php echo $dbSessionDurationTime; ?>';
        function displaytimer(){
            var hours = Math.floor(millis / 36e5),
                mins = Math.floor((millis % 36e5) / 6e4),
            secs = Math.floor((millis % 6e4) / 1000);
            $('.count').html(hours+':'+mins+':'+secs);  
        }
        setInterval(function(){
            millis -= 1000;
            displaytimer();
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at your convertion, it's returning `949219200` where in fact it should have returned `5400000`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Timer</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <?php
      $dbSessionDuration = "1:30:00";

      $time   = explode(":", $dbSessionDuration);

      $hour   = $time[0] * 60 * 60 * 1000;
      $minute = $time[1] * 60 * 1000;
      $sec    = $time[2] * 1000;

      $dbSessionDurationTime = $hour + $minute + $sec;

    ?>
    <div class="count"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var millis = '<?php echo $dbSessionDurationTime; ?>';
        function displaytimer(){
            var hours = Math.floor(millis / 36e5),
                mins = Math.floor((millis % 36e5) / 6e4),
                secs = Math.floor((millis % 6e4) / 1000);
                $('.count').html(hours+':'+mins+':'+secs);  
        }
        setInterval(function(){
            millis -= 1000;
            displaytimer();
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
```

Now the `$dbSessionDurationTime` will contain the right number of milisecs of `5400000` Here is a working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpGYKo of course the php part its not there but you can see the timer working as you want it to.